# contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

i getting some response which contains some information, i stored value in dictionary format in NSMutableArray for example

```
{name :david, email : xxx.com},{name: david, email : yay.com},{name : david, email : zzz.com} {name: Annie, email : annie.com},{name: George, email : ger.com}
```

i have two label Name and Email. when i press Label Action i displayed all the usernames in that i selecting name as "daniel"

Now i going for second label called Email Action in that i want only email list of "daniel" its contains three mail i have to displayed in tableview

here i tried this code but didn't worked for me

```
let data = NameList.filter{($0 as! [String:String])["Name"]!.containsString(NameLabel.text!)}.map { x in return x["email"]!}
            //                print(data)


 detailsArray = data
```

my output log as follows :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
>   reason: '-[UITableView
>   _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (2) beyond bounds (1) for section (0).

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that your table does not have any row at index 2. It means that your table view consists of 2 rows and maximum range of indexPath.row can be 1 (because row index of a UITableView starts from 0). Whenever you will call a row at index path beyond range of the table, it will throw an error.